# Can I use a Verizon iPad mini with Wi-Fi only?

Tags: ipad

A friend just gave me his Verizon LTW iPad mini. I don't have Verizon.

Do I need to remove the SIM card to use it on Wi-Fi only? What problems will I encounter not having Verizon and trying to use this device? What settings do I need to turn off to disable Verizon's service on this device? How does this SIM card get removed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with Wifi only. It may try to connect to cellular data automatically so in Settings you can disable cellular data.

You dont have to worry about the SIM card.